# Cascading interfaces for wrapping VSTO Microsoft.Office.Interop

Tags: vb.net

I have created my own wrapping framework for the COM interfaces exposed via `Microsoft.Office.Interop`.

---

## MIRRORING WRAPPERS

The first purpose is to be able to unit test the rest of my applications, and also to be able to intuitively log some of the calls.

The wrapping is achieved through 2 layers of interfaces: the first layer exposes office-wide members, whilst the second layer exposes application-specific members.

*Note that for the sake of readability I provide here a simplified sample. Only the variety of objects, types, and member names change from the original.*

```
#Region "Office Wrappers"

Interface IApplication(Of Out T As IFile(Of IVariable))

    ReadOnly Property Documents As IEnumerable(Of T)

End Interface

Interface IFile(Of Out T As IVariable)

    ReadOnly Property Variables As IEnumerable(Of T)

    ReadOnly Property Name As String

End Interface

Interface IVariable

    Property SomeProperty As String

End Interface

#End Region


#Region "Word Wrappers"

Interface IWordApplication(Of Out T As IWordDocument(Of IWordVariable))
    Inherits IApplication(Of T)


End Interface

Interface IWordDocument(Of Out T As IWordVariable)
    Inherits IFile(Of T)

    ReadOnly Property Paragraphs As IEnumerable(Of IWordParagraph)

End Interface

Interface IWordVariable
    Inherits IVariable

End Interface

Interface IWordParagraph

    Property SomeProperty As String

End Interface

#End Region
```

These interfaces are instantiated via a Factory which is injected and creates the relevant object for a given object which implements an `Office.Interop` interface.

```
#Region "Word objects"


Interface IWordFactory

    Function Create(Application As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application) As IWordApplication(Of IWordDocument(Of IWordVariable))

    Function Create(Document As IEnumerable(Of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document)) As IEnumerable(Of IWordDocument(Of IWordVariable))

    Function Create(Paragraph As IEnumerable(Of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph)) As IEnumerable(Of IWordParagraph)

    Function Create(Variable As IEnumerable(Of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Variable)) As IEnumerable(Of IWordVariable)

End Interface


Class WordApplication
    Implements IWordApplication(Of IWordDocument(Of IWordVariable))

    Protected ThisApplication As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
    Protected ThisFactory As IWordFactory

    Sub New(Application As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application, Factory As IWordFactory)
        Me.ThisApplication = Application
        Me.ThisFactory = Factory
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Documents As IEnumerable(Of IWordDocument(Of IWordVariable)) Implements IApplication(Of IWordDocument(Of IWordVariable)).Documents
        Get
            Return Me.ThisFactory.Create(Me.ThisApplication.Documents.Cast(Of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document))
        End Get
    End Property

End Class


Class WordDocument
    Implements IWordDocument(Of IWordVariable)

    Protected ThisDocument As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
    Protected ThisFactory As IWordFactory

    Sub New(Document As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document, Factory As IWordFactory)
        Me.ThisDocument = Document
        Me.ThisFactory = Factory
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Name As String Implements IFile(Of IWordVariable).Name
        Get
            Return Me.ThisDocument.Name
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Paragraphs As IEnumerable(Of IWordParagraph) Implements IWordDocument(Of IWordVariable).Paragraphs
        Get
            Return Me.ThisFactory.Create(Me.ThisDocument.Paragraphs.Cast(Of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph))
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Variables As IEnumerable(Of IWordVariable) Implements IFile(Of IWordVariable).Variables
        Get
            Return Me.ThisFactory.Create(Me.ThisDocument.Variables.Cast(Of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Variable))
        End Get
    End Property

End Class

Class WordParagraph
    Implements IWordParagraph

    Protected ThisParagraph As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph
    Protected ThisFactory As IWordFactory

    Sub New(Paragraph As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document, Factory As IWordFactory)
        Me.ThisParagraph = Paragraph
        Me.ThisFactory = Factory
        Me.SomeProperty = "Something"
    End Sub

    Public Property SomeProperty As String Implements IWordParagraph.SomeProperty

End Class

Class WordVariable
    Implements IWordVariable

    Protected ThisVariable As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Variable
    Protected ThisFactory As IWordFactory

    Sub New(Variable As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document, Factory As IWordFactory)
        Me.ThisVariable = Variable
        Me.ThisFactory = Factory
        Me.SomeProperty = "Something"
    End Sub

    Public Property SomeProperty As String Implements IVariable.SomeProperty

End Class


#End Region
```

---

## EXTENDING THE WRAPPERS

On top of these basic mirroring wrappers, I have a set of custom functionalities which extend the possibilities offered by each wrapper. These functionalities are not directly included in the above wrappers so that they can be unit tested.
Again, two layers, following the same pattern:

```
#Region "Extension of Office Wrappers"


Interface IExtApplication(Of Out T As IExtFile(Of IVariable))
    Inherits IApplication(Of T)

End Interface

Interface IExtFile(Of Out T As IVariable)
    Inherits IFile(Of T)

    Sub SomeCustomMethod()

End Interface

#End Region


#Region "Extension of Word Wrappers"

Interface IExtWordApplication
    Inherits IWordApplication(Of IExtWordDocument), IExtApplication(Of IExtWordDocument)

End Interface

Interface IExtWordDocument
    Inherits IWordDocument(Of IExtWordVariable), IExtFile(Of IExtWordVariable)

    Function SomeCustomFunction(Parameter As Boolean) As Integer

End Interface

Interface IExtWordVariable
    Inherits IWordVariable

End Interface

Interface IExtWordParagraph
    Inherits IWordParagraph

    Sub SomeCustomAction()

End Interface

#End Region
```

They are implemented following the same principle as before:

```
#Region "Extended Word objects"


Interface IExtWordFactory
    Inherits IWordFactory

    Function Extend(Application As IWordApplication(Of IWordDocument(Of IWordVariable))) As IExtWordApplication

    Function Extend(Document As IEnumerable(Of IWordDocument(Of IWordVariable))) As IEnumerable(Of IExtWordDocument)

    Function Extend(Paragraph As IEnumerable(Of IWordParagraph)) As IEnumerable(Of IExtWordParagraph)

    Function Extend(Variable As IEnumerable(Of IWordVariable)) As IEnumerable(Of IExtWordVariable)

End Interface


Class ExtWordApplication
    Inherits WordApplication
    Implements IExtWordApplication

    Protected Shadows ThisFactory As IExtWordFactory

    Sub New(Application As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application, ExtFactory As IExtWordFactory)
        MyBase.New(Application, ExtFactory)
    End Sub

    Public Overloads ReadOnly Property Documents As IEnumerable(Of IExtWordDocument) Implements IApplication(Of IExtWordDocument).Documents
        Get
            Return Me.ThisFactory.Extend(MyBase.Documents)
        End Get
    End Property

End Class


Class ExtWordDocument
    Inherits WordDocument
    Implements IExtWordDocument

    Protected Shadows ThisFactory As IExtWordFactory

    Sub New(Document As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document, ExtFactory As IExtWordFactory)
        MyBase.New(Document, ExtFactory)
    End Sub

    Public Overloads ReadOnly Property Name As String Implements IExtFile(Of IExtWordVariable).Name
        Get
            Return MyBase.Name
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overloads ReadOnly Property Variables As IEnumerable(Of IExtWordVariable) Implements IFile(Of IExtWordVariable).Variables
        Get
            Return Me.ThisFactory.Extend(MyBase.Variables)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overloads ReadOnly Property Paragraphs As IEnumerable(Of IWordParagraph) Implements IWordDocument(Of IExtWordVariable).Paragraphs
        Get
            Return Me.ThisFactory.Extend(MyBase.Paragraphs)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub SomeCustomMethod() Implements IExtFile(Of IExtWordVariable).SomeCustomMethod
        'DoSomething
    End Sub

    Public Function SomeCustomFunction(Parameter As Boolean) As Integer Implements IExtWordDocument.SomeCustomFunction
        Return 123456
    End Function

End Class


Class ExtWordParagraph
    Inherits WordParagraph
    Implements IExtWordParagraph

    Protected Shadows ThisFactory As IExtWordFactory

    Sub New(Paragraph As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph, ExtFactory As IExtWordFactory)
        MyBase.New(Paragraph, ExtFactory)
    End Sub

    Public Sub SomeCustomAction() Implements IExtWordParagraph.SomeCustomAction
        'DoSomething
    End Sub

End Class


Class ExtWordVariable
    Inherits WordVariable
    Implements IExtWordVariable

    Protected Shadows ThisFactory As IExtWordFactory

    Sub New(Variable As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Variable, ExtFactory As IExtWordFactory)
        MyBase.New(Variable, ExtFactory)
    End Sub

End Class


#End Region
```

---

## USAGE

An extended factory is injected and used to instantiate the extended wrapper of the  `Office.Interop` application. The reference to the Extended Application is then injected in all subsequent objects required for my models.
Some models are application-spcific, some are designed to proceed without worrying whether we are dealing with a Word Document or an Excel Workbook:

```
Module Main

    Sub Startup(InjectedFactory As IExtWordFactory)

        Dim MyFactory As IExtWordFactory = InjectedFactory
        Dim InteropApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
        Dim MyApp As IExtWordApplication = MyFactory.Extend(MyFactory.Create(InteropApp))

        FromOfficeWideOperationsLibrary(MyApp)
        FromWordSpecificOperationsLibrary(MyApp)

    End Sub

    Sub FromOfficeWideOperationsLibrary(MyApp As IExtApplication(Of IExtFile(Of IVariable)))

        For Each MyOpenFile As IExtFile(Of IVariable) In MyApp.Documents
            MsgBox($"File name is {MyOpenFile.Name}")
            MyOpenFile.SomeCustomMethod()
        Next

    End Sub

    Sub FromWordSpecificOperationsLibrary(MyApp As IExtWordApplication)

        For Each MyOpenDoc As IExtWordDocument In MyApp.Documents
            MsgBox($"Document has {MyOpenDoc.Paragraphs.Count} paragraphs")
        Next

    End Sub

End Module
```

---

## DISCUSSION

I am far from being satisfied by this architecture:

1. The first frustration is that when dealing with office-wide models, I am forced to repeatedly type `MyApp As IExtApplication(Of IExtFile(Of IVariable))`, where a simple `MyApp As IextApplication` would be much cleaner.
2. If I add a member to `IApplication`, I subsequently need to add an `Overloads` member in `ExtWordApplication` even if it is already implemented in `WordApplication` (look in the code above how the implementation of `Overlaods ReadOnly Property Name as String` is needlessly required for `ExtWordDocument`)
3. Although some extending objects are equal to their non extended version, it is still required to implement them (empty). For example, if `IExtFile` did not include any additional member when compared to `IFile`, I would still require to define the interface and its implementations so that starting from `ExtWordApplication`, it would be possible to travel the tree all the way down to `ExtWordParagraph`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have managed to substantially improve code by:

1. Relying on aliases: `Imports IObject = IFoo(Of IBar(Of Something))`
2. Injecting the Office-wide objects inside Application-specific objects, rather than incorporating the base functionalities via Class inheritance. This allows for better unit testing.

Any suggestions are still very welcome :)

```
Imports IApplication = MyNamespace.IApplication(Of MyNamespace.IFile(Of MyNamespace.IVariable))
Imports IFile = MyNamespace.IFile(Of MyNamespace.IVariable)
Imports IVariable = MyNamespace.IVariable

Imports IWordApplication = MyNamespace.IWordApplication(Of MyNamespace.IWordDocument(Of MyNamespace.IWordVariable))
Imports IWordDocument = MyNamespace.IWordDocument(Of MyNamespace.IWordVariable)

Imports IExtApplication = MyNamespace.IExtApplication(Of MyNamespace.IExtFile(Of MyNamespace.IVariable))
Imports IExtFile = MyNamespace.IExtFile(Of MyNamespace.IVariable)


#Region "Office Wrappers"


Interface IApplication(Of Out T As IFile)

    ReadOnly Property Documents As IEnumerable(Of T)

End Interface

Interface IFile(Of Out T As IVariable)

    ReadOnly Property Variables As IEnumerable(Of T)

    ReadOnly Property Name As String

End Interface

Interface IVariable

    Property SomeProperty As String

End Interface


#End Region


#Region "Extension of Office Wrappers"


Interface IExtApplication(Of Out T As IExtFile)
    Inherits IApplication(Of T)

End Interface

Interface IExtFile(Of Out T As IVariable)
    Inherits IFile(Of T)

    Sub SomeCustomMethod()

End Interface


#End Region


#Region "Word Wrappers"


Interface IWordApplication(Of Out T As IWordDocument)
    Inherits IApplication(Of T)


End Interface

Interface IWordDocument(Of Out T As IWordVariable)
    Inherits IFile(Of T)

    ReadOnly Property Paragraphs As IEnumerable(Of IWordParagraph)

End Interface

Interface IWordVariable
    Inherits IVariable

End Interface

Interface IWordParagraph

    Property SomeProperty As String

End Interface


#End Region


#Region "Extension of Word Wrappers"


Interface IExtWordApplication
    Inherits IWordApplication(Of IExtWordDocument), IExtApplication(Of IExtWordDocument)

End Interface

Interface IExtWordDocument
    Inherits IWordDocument(Of IExtWordVariable), IExtFile(Of IExtWordVariable)

    Function SomeCustomFunction(Parameter As Boolean) As Integer

End Interface

Interface IExtWordVariable
    Inherits IWordVariable

End Interface

Interface IExtWordParagraph
    Inherits IWordParagraph

    Sub SomeCustomAction()

End Interface


#End Region


#Region "Word objects"


Interface IWordFactory

    Function Create(Application As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application) As IWordApplication

    Function Create(Document As IEnumerable(Of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document)) As IEnumerable(Of IWordDocument)

    Function Create(Paragraph As IEnumerable(Of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph)) As IEnumerable(Of IWordParagraph)

    Function Create(Variable As IEnumerable(Of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Variable)) As IEnumerable(Of IWordVariable)

End Interface


Class WordApplication
    Implements IWordApplication

    Protected ThisApplication As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
    Protected ThisFactory As IWordFactory

    Sub New(Application As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application, Factory As IWordFactory)
        Me.ThisApplication = Application
        Me.ThisFactory = Factory
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Documents As IEnumerable(Of IWordDocument) Implements IApplication(Of IWordDocument).Documents
        Get
            Return Me.ThisFactory.Create(Me.ThisApplication.Documents.Cast(Of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document))
        End Get
    End Property

End Class


Class WordDocument
    Implements IWordDocument

    Protected ThisDocument As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
    Protected ThisFactory As IWordFactory

    Sub New(Document As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document, Factory As IWordFactory)
        Me.ThisDocument = Document
        Me.ThisFactory = Factory
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Name As String Implements IFile(Of IWordVariable).Name
        Get
            Return Me.ThisDocument.Name
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Paragraphs As IEnumerable(Of IWordParagraph) Implements IWordDocument.Paragraphs
        Get
            Return Me.ThisFactory.Create(Me.ThisDocument.Paragraphs.Cast(Of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph))
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Variables As IEnumerable(Of IWordVariable) Implements IFile(Of IWordVariable).Variables
        Get
            Return Me.ThisFactory.Create(Me.ThisDocument.Variables.Cast(Of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Variable))
        End Get
    End Property

End Class

Class WordParagraph
    Implements IWordParagraph

    Protected ThisParagraph As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph
    Protected ThisFactory As IWordFactory

    Sub New(Paragraph As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document, Factory As IWordFactory)
        Me.ThisParagraph = Paragraph
        Me.ThisFactory = Factory
        Me.SomeProperty = "Something"
    End Sub

    Public Property SomeProperty As String Implements IWordParagraph.SomeProperty

End Class

Class WordVariable
    Implements IWordVariable

    Protected ThisVariable As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Variable
    Protected ThisFactory As IWordFactory

    Sub New(Variable As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document, Factory As IWordFactory)
        Me.ThisVariable = Variable
        Me.ThisFactory = Factory
        Me.SomeProperty = "Something"
    End Sub

    Public Property SomeProperty As String Implements IVariable.SomeProperty

End Class


#End Region


#Region "Extended Word objects"


Interface IExtWordFactory
    Inherits IWordFactory

    Function Extend(Application As IWordApplication(Of IWordDocument(Of IWordVariable))) As IExtWordApplication

    Function Extend(Document As IEnumerable(Of IWordDocument(Of IWordVariable))) As IEnumerable(Of IExtWordDocument)

    Function Extend(Paragraph As IEnumerable(Of IWordParagraph)) As IEnumerable(Of IExtWordParagraph)

    Function Extend(Variable As IEnumerable(Of IWordVariable)) As IEnumerable(Of IExtWordVariable)

End Interface


Class ExtWordApplication
    Implements IExtWordApplication

    Private ThisWordApplication As IWordApplication
    Protected Shadows ThisFactory As IExtWordFactory

    Sub New(WordApplication As IWordApplication, ExtFactory As IExtWordFactory)
        Me.ThisWordApplication = WordApplication
    End Sub

    Public Overloads ReadOnly Property Documents As IEnumerable(Of IExtWordDocument) Implements IApplication(Of IExtWordDocument).Documents
        Get
            Return Me.ThisFactory.Extend(Me.ThisWordApplication.Documents)
        End Get
    End Property

End Class


Class ExtWordDocument
    Implements IExtWordDocument

    Private ThisWordDocument As IWordDocument
    Protected Shadows ThisFactory As IExtWordFactory

    Sub New(WordDocument As IWordDocument, ExtFactory As IExtWordFactory)
        Me.ThisWordDocument = WordDocument
    End Sub

    Public Overloads ReadOnly Property Name As String Implements IExtFile(Of IExtWordVariable).Name
        Get
            Return Me.ThisWordDocument.Name
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overloads ReadOnly Property Variables As IEnumerable(Of IExtWordVariable) Implements IFile(Of IExtWordVariable).Variables
        Get
            Return Me.ThisFactory.Extend(Me.ThisWordDocument.Variables)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overloads ReadOnly Property Paragraphs As IEnumerable(Of IWordParagraph) Implements IWordDocument(Of IExtWordVariable).Paragraphs
        Get
            Return Me.ThisFactory.Extend(Me.ThisWordDocument.Paragraphs)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub SomeCustomMethod() Implements IExtFile(Of IExtWordVariable).SomeCustomMethod
        'DoSomething
    End Sub

    Public Function SomeCustomFunction(Parameter As Boolean) As Integer Implements IExtWordDocument.SomeCustomFunction
        Return 123456
    End Function

End Class


Class ExtWordParagraph
    Implements IExtWordParagraph

    Private ThisWordParagraph As IWordParagraph
    Protected Shadows ThisFactory As IExtWordFactory

    Sub New(WordParagraph As IWordParagraph, ExtFactory As IExtWordFactory)
        Me.ThisWordParagraph = WordParagraph
    End Sub

    Public Property SomeProperty As String Implements IWordParagraph.SomeProperty
        Get
            Return Me.ThisWordParagraph.SomeProperty
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.ThisWordParagraph.SomeProperty = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub SomeCustomAction() Implements IExtWordParagraph.SomeCustomAction
        'DoSomething
    End Sub

End Class


Class ExtWordVariable
    Implements IExtWordVariable

    Private ThisWordVariable As IWordVariable
    Protected Shadows ThisFactory As IExtWordFactory

    Sub New(WordVariable As IWordVariable, ExtFactory As IExtWordFactory)
        Me.ThisWordVariable = WordVariable
    End Sub

    Public Property SomeProperty As String Implements IVariable.SomeProperty
        Get
            Return Me.ThisWordVariable.SomeProperty
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.ThisWordVariable.SomeProperty = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class


#End Region


Class Main

    Sub Startup(InjectedFactory As IExtWordFactory)

        Dim MyFactory As IExtWordFactory = InjectedFactory
        Dim InteropApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application = Nothing 'Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
        Dim MyApp As IExtWordApplication = MyFactory.Extend(MyFactory.Create(InteropApp))

        FromOfficeWideOperationsLibrary(MyApp)
        FromWordSpecificOperationsLibrary(MyApp)

    End Sub

    Sub FromOfficeWideOperationsLibrary(MyApp As IExtApplication)

        For Each MyOpenFile As IExtFile In MyApp.Documents
            MsgBox($"File name is {MyOpenFile.Name}")
            MyOpenFile.SomeCustomMethod()
        Next

    End Sub

    Sub FromWordSpecificOperationsLibrary(MyApp As IExtWordApplication)

        For Each MyOpenDoc As IExtWordDocument In MyApp.Documents
            MsgBox($"Document has {MyOpenDoc.Paragraphs.Count} paragraphs")
        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```